# Using Trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, output, input

This is a fairly simple notation problem. I am trying to compute ArcTan of the point (5,2). I have the code:

```
ArcTan[5,2]
```

which outputs:

```
ArcTan[2/5]
```

Do I have to clarify that I would like my output in terms of radians or Pi? Technically the output is correct, but not very useful.

Ideally I would found that the Arctan[5,2]=Arctan(2/5)=.3805. Which I guess would be found by using N[function]. Any ideas on how to get where it is Pi*x such that x in Reals?

I have used the page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html. For help

Comment: Are you looking for `N`?

Comment: N as in the numerical version? For that I just do N[function]

Comment: Could you write down your expected result?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: Arctan is spelled `ArcTan` (i.e., capitol **T**) in Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had that on the code, but stil nothing

Comment: If you want a numerical result you can use `ArcTan[5,2.]`. Note the period following the 2. This will output it in radians. If you want degrees use `ArcTan[5,2.]/Degree`.

Comment: Thank you @JackLaVigne. I would put that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a numerical result you can use

```
ArcTan[5, 2.]

(* 0.380506 *)
```

Note the period following the 2. This will output it in radians.

If you want degrees use

```
ArcTan[5, 2.]/Degree

(* 21.8014 *)
```